# Gauss integral with sine.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to calculate this $ \int^{\infty}_0 e^{- \alpha x^2} \sin(\beta x) \,\mathrm{d} x $ ? I've tried to get a differential equation, but is seems not to be easily solvable.

Comment: Do you know how to find the fourier transform of $ e^{-\alpha x^2 }$?

Comment: Write sin in terms of the expoential, complete the square of the exponent, and obtain the integral in terms of the error function erf.

Comment: I know that there is a simpler solution that in terms of erf(I mean elementary functions).

Comment: One nice thing to notice is that if we call the integral $y(\alpha,\beta)$, 
$$
{\partial y \over \partial \alpha} = {\partial ^2y\over\partial \beta^2},
$$
meaning that the integral is a solution to the heat equation with the condition $y(\alpha,0)=0$.

Note that Wolfram Alpha evaluates
$$
y(1,1) = F\left(1\over2\right),
$$
where $F(\cdot)$ is Dawson's Integral, 
$$
F(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\int_0^{x} \mathrm{e}^{y^2} \ \mathrm{d}y.
$$
This is, I believe, a solution to the heat equation, and can be written in terms of the imaginary error function.

Comment: Mhenni, yes, I do. But in that case it would have different limits of integral...

Comment: OK, thanks every one, I'm so disappointed that it is not elementary.

Comment: It is what it is!

Comment: See this...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527341/show-that-int-0-infty-e-x2-sin2xb-dx-e-b2-int-0b-ex2-dx/527410#527410

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that the value of the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) is $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt\frac\pi2$ , and recalling [Euler's famous formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, discovered by [Abraham de Moivre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Derivation), the integral becomes:

$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\sin(bx)dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\Im\left(e^{ix}\right)dx=\Im\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-(ax^2-ibx)}dx\right)=$$

$$=\Im\bigg(\int_0^\infty \exp\bigg[-\bigg(x\sqrt a-i\frac b{2\sqrt a}\bigg)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}\bigg]dx\bigg)=\Im\bigg(\int_{-ic}^{\infty-ic}e^{-(t^2+c^2)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt a}\bigg)=$$

$$=\frac{e^{-c^2}}{\sqrt a}\cdot\Im\bigg(\int_{-ic}^{\infty-ic}e^{-t^2}dt\bigg)=\frac{e^{-c^2}}{\sqrt a}\cdot\Im\bigg[\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\bigg(1+\text{Erf}(ic)\bigg)\bigg]=\sqrt\frac\pi a\cdot\frac{e^{-c^2}}2\cdot\Im\Big[\text{Erf}(ic)\Big],$$

where $c=-\displaystyle\frac b{2\sqrt a}$ , $t=x\sqrt a-ic$ , $\Im$ represents the imaginary part , and *Erf* is the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this integral cannot solved by ODE approach.

See http://tw.knowledge.yahoo.com/question/article?qid=1712010766078 or http://tw.knowledge.yahoo.com/question/article?qid=1712010194980.