# How to integrate $e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}\cos(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have the following integral I'm trying to solve: 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
how to solve this, please help me.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28e%5E%7B-x%5E2%2F4%7Dcos%28x%29%29dx+from+0+to+infinity

Comment: it seems that it has not solution in elementary function

Comment: WA gives $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{e}$

Comment: Hint: last answer of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540292/gauss-integral-with-sine

Comment: i know what result gives WA,but i need to know how can i get this answer.

Comment: Try writing $\cos x = \frac12(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$ and using contour integration?

Answer (score 1):

Since the integrand is symmetric in $x$,
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/4}\cos (x) dx=\frac{1}{2}{\text{Re}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4}x^2+ix\right)dx.
$$
Since
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4}x^2+ix\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4}(x-2i)^2-1\right)dx=\frac{1}{e}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2/4}dy=\frac{1}{e}(2\sqrt{\pi}),
$$
after making the substitution $y=x-2i$, you get
$$
I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e}.
$$